# R Leaflet PopupGraph - addPopupGraphs on map_marker_click

Tags: r, shiny, popup, r-leaflet

I would like to open a popup with a unique plot for each of my marker in it on a map_marker_click using r leaflet and the leafpop library.

For each point when the user click on them the plot to display is computed.

Below is a reproductible code but it doesn't return any error.
Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)


id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4)
lat <- c(49.823, 49.823, 49.823, 49.823, 58.478, 58.478, 57.478 , 57.478 , 57.478, 38.551)
lng <- c(-10.854, -10.854, -10.854, -10.854, -11.655, -11.655, 2.021 , 2.021 , 2.021, 5.256)
type <- c("A","C","B","B","C","A","B","A","C","B")
date <- c(152.5,307.5,145,481,152,109.5,258.5,107.5,186.5,150)
start <- c(123,235,135,192,149,101,205,75,155,100)
stop <- c(182,380,155,289,155,218,312,140,218,200)
myData <- data.frame(id,type,date,start,stop,lat,lng)


chronogramme<- function(dataId){

  dataFiltered<-filter(myData,id==dataId)

  p<- ggplot(dataFiltered,aes(type,date))+
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=start,ymax=stop),size=5)+
    coord_flip()
  return(p)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Sortie map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(
        layerId=~id,
        data = myData,
        lat = myData$lat,
        lng = myData$lng,
        radius = 5,
        color = 'blue',
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 1,
        group = 'markers'
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    p <- chronogramme(input$map_marker_click$id)
    isolate({
      leafletProxy("map") %>% addPopupGraphs(list(p), group = 'markers')
    })
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response, the problem is that I have many many data on my application so iterate all the plot doesn't work.

However, I've found another solution : store each created plot temporarily as svg, and display them with addPopus() :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)
library(lattice)


id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4)
lat <- c(49.823, 49.823, 49.823, 49.823, 58.478, 58.478, 57.478 , 57.478 , 57.478, 38.551)
lng <- c(-10.854, -10.854, -10.854, -10.854, -11.655, -11.655, 2.021 , 2.021 , 2.021, 5.256)
type <- c("A","C","B","B","C","A","B","A","C","B")
date <- c(152.5,307.5,145,481,152,109.5,258.5,107.5,186.5,150)
start <- c(123,235,135,192,149,101,205,75,155,100)
stop <- c(182,380,155,289,155,218,312,140,218,200)
myData <- data.frame(id,type,date,start,stop,lat,lng)

folder <- tempfile()
dir.create(folder)

chronogramme<- function(dataId){

  dataFiltered<-filter(myData,id==dataId)

  p<- ggplot(dataFiltered,aes(type,date))+
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=start,ymax=stop),size=5)+
    coord_flip()
  return(p)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Sortie map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(
        layerId=~id,
        data = myData,
        lat = myData$lat,
        lng = myData$lng,
        radius = 5,
        color = 'blue',
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 1
      )
  })

  # When map is clicked, show a popup with city info
  showPopup <- function(id, lat, lng) {
    chrngr <- chronogramme(id)
    svg(filename= paste(folder,"plot.svg", sep = "/"), 
        width = 500 * 0.005, height = 300 * 0.005)
    print(chrngr)
    dev.off()

    content <- paste(readLines(paste(folder,"plot.svg",sep="/")), collapse = "")

    leafletProxy("map") %>% addPopups(lng, lat, content, layerId = id)
  }

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_marker_click
    if (is.null(event))
      return()

    isolate({
      showPopup(event$id, event$lat, event$lng)
    })
  })

}



# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I have approached this with maps is to use `addPopupGraphs` after adding the circle markers in `renderLeaflet` (as opposed to `observeEvent` detecting clicks on the markers).

In this case, you can create a list of your plots, such as:

```
p_all <- lapply(myData$id, chronogramme)
```

Then use `p_all` list as follows:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(
        layerId=~id,
        data = myData,
        lat = myData$lat,
        lng = myData$lng,
        radius = 5,
        color = 'blue',
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 1,
        group = 'markers'
      ) %>%
      addPopupGraphs(p_all, group = 'markers')
  })
```

And then you would not need `observeEvent`.

Would this work?